# Why pumping lemma for context free languages do not have bound on first part of string?

Tags: context-free-language, pumping-lemma

Pumping lemma for Regular Languages (RLs) states that

> For any Regular Language (*L*) there is a number p such that for any string *w* in *L* such that length of *w,|w|>=p* then there is a partition of *w = uvy*, where ***|uv|<=p**, |v|>0* so that for every *i* in whole numbers *uv^iy* will also be in *L*.

But in the case of pumping lemma for Context-Free Languages (CFLs)

> For any CFL (*L*) there is a number *p* such that for any string *w* in *L* such that length of *w,|w|>=p* then there is a partition of *w = uvxyz* such that length of substring *|vxy|<=p, |vy|>0* then for every *i* in whole numbers, uv^ixy^iz will also be in *L*

My question is in case of RLs we bounded the starting part of string *u* by saying that |uv|<=p, but we have no bound on *u* in case of CFLs why?